# error code during install migration is not in english, how to change it to english?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

*******\wamp\www\laravel>**php artisan migrate:install**

> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] AccΦs refusΘ pour
>   l'utilisateur: 'homestead'@'@local   host' (mot de passe: OUI)

Can anyone please kindly tell me how to change the language to English? It would really help me in the future. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using Wamp server's mySQL..

1. Left click wamp server icon
2. hover MySQL
3. left click my.ini

[image]

On the text editor,find this line:

```
lc-messages=fr_FR
```

And change to:

```
lc-messages=en_US
```

After saving the changes,you need to restart Mysql service.

[image]

By the way the error you get means:

```
 access denied for user: homestead'@'@localhost'(password: yes)
```

Be sure you correctly configure laravel to use on wamp-server and your database settings are correct..

you may need to check both `app/config/databese.php` and `.env` file in your root directory..

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for helping me. Really nice tutorial on how to fix my errors. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

To change the error message language in MySQL server, you should first login to MySQL server with 
`mysql -u homestead -p`, the default password for user 'homestead' should be 'secret' unless you changed it. After you login, set the language to english by executing `SET lc_messages = 'en_US';`.